# Similar Data Structures in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, data-structures

I am trying to port this application from PHP to Java. PHP makes things easy with their associate name arrays and the extract() function. For Java I am thinking about using a HashMap to simulate the Arrays in PHP. Is there a better data structure to use than this? And is there a function similar to extract in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order you put the values into the HashMap, then look into using LinkedHashMap.  But HashMap is a decent choice if you don't have that requirement.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes HashMap (or TreeMap, depending on your memory needs) will work perfectly for you.

There is nothing like extract in Java.

Consider the `java.util.Map` interface: It requires a Key object and a Value object.

In PHP you can take the value of a `Key` and turn it into a variable name.

In Java, you are required to explicitly define your variables - you cannot define new variables with names based on the runtime values of other variables.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap will do, but there is no Java equivalent to extract(), because of the fundamentally different background of the language.